# Making PDF annotations with Quartz 2D

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, quartz-2d

I am working on PDFs using [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves/). I'm unable to figure out how to make annotations. I haven't used Quartz 2D much and would like some direction

Answer (score 1):

Adding *write* annotation support is hard.

Quartz 2D won't help you there.

You need to manually parse the PDF. (e.g. with NSScanner) and build up the XRef tree of all the PDF objects. Then you're writing a new trailer that replaces the /Page object and attaches all new annotation data. It's quite hard to get right, and the 2000 pages PDF reference is not very helpful on that. I worked the better part of the year for proper annotation support (Highlight, Underscore, Strikeout, Ink, Note, ...).

And when you want highlight annotations, you also want text selection (else the user would have to free-draw a highlight - not a nice experience.) Getting the correct frames for the text glyphs for all PDF font types is another level of horror; in PDF there's no notion of a word or a column. Just single glyphs. The rest is algorithms and guessing.

I even spoke with some Apple engineers how they did it [text selection, annotations], and they told me a three-person team worked about three years on their implementation.